# Python pandas excel How set color to specific row

Tags: python, pandas

Hello i open excel file with pandas and i need need set color to specific row if in into the row have specific string value. How do this?

Comment: You need to use another library that allows you more control on Excel sheets.

Comment: Pandas has styling options that should let you do this: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html